# Data frame column translation

Tags: python, pandas

I need to translate a column in a dataframe from english to arabic the code runs fine but it don't translate the words instead it gives me this in the new column I am translating in

```
Translated(src=en,dst=ar,text='the sentence in english)
```

Here is the code I am using

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_excel('HS_CODES_UNITS.xlsx')
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
file['Product description in arabic'] = file['Product Description in English'].apply(translator.translate, src='en', dest='ar')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug due to a change in the Google API. A new alpha version of googletrans with a fix was released a few minutes ago.

Install the alpha version like this:

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

**Important thing to note:**
You have to specify a service url, otherwise the same error still occurs. So this should work:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator(service_urls=['translate.googleapis.com'])
translator.translate("Der Himmel ist blau und ich mag Bananen", dest='en')
```

But his still returns the error (at least for me):

```
translator = Translator()
translator.translate("Der Himmel ist blau und ich mag Bananen", dest='en')
```

See the discussion here for details and updates: https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/pull/237

Answer (score 0):

`translator.translate` returns an object of type `Translated`. The translated text can be accessed via the property `text`. Check official docs [here](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

#### Fix

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'English': ['this is an apple', 'that is a mango']})
translator = Translator(service_urls=[
      'translate.google.com',
    ])
df['Arabic' ] = df['English'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, src='en', dest='ar').text)
print (df)
```

Output:

```
    English             Arabic
0   this is an apple    هذه تفاحة
1   that is a mango     هذا مانجو
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping

when I apply this code I get this error
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Looks like sometimes `googletrans` api fails. I ran it second time and it suceeded.